# Проблема с восстановлением резервной копии базы данных

Tags: python, база-данных, psql, восстановление

Мне надо сделать резервную копию базы данных. когда запускаю свой код, на словах удаленные данные из резерва восстанавливаются, на деле нет.

```
import os
BACKUP_CMD = 'pg_dump --clean --dbname=postgresql://postgresql:password@host:port/dbname > C:/python_project/backup.dump'
os.system(BACKUP_CMD)
```

код с резервной копией работает на ура

```
import os
cmd = f'psql -d dbname -U username -p port -h host -f C:/python_project/backup.dump'
os.environ['PGPASSWORD'] = 'mypassword'
os.system(cmd)
```

При запуске кода с восстановлением данных он прописывает выполняемые действия, но на деле ничего не восстановил. я не могу понять в чем причина. все утилиты установлены и обновлены до самой последней версии. 
Прошу помогите, хочу сегодня уже закончить свои мучения.

Я пробовала всё, смотрела в инете, спрашивала у ии. все в один голос говорят, что проблема в правах файла копии базы данных. посмотрела, всё с правами нормально, я могу вносить изменения.

Comment: Могут быть разные варианты ошибок. Например существуют активные коннекты к этой БД, что мешает менять схему. Как вариант, перед восстановлением выполнить команду `SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid) FROM pg_stat_activity` чтобы оборвать все активные подключения. Другой вариант, наличие данных, завязанных на индексы, которые не могут быть просто так перезаписаны. Тогда, при создании дампа, надо использовать параметры удаления БД и создания заново. Не может быть чтобы в логах что-то да не отразилось